# echo to file and terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, echo

Is there a method I can echo some value into a file and terminal in 1 line instead of doing two echo

```
echo "testing" >> file.txt #to file but not terminal
echo "testing" #to terminal but not file
```

Comment: From your code, I guess you mean _to stdout_ instead of _to terminal_. In this case, have a look an _man tee_.